# Synonym for policeman/policewoman?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am putting together a scene which has a policeman and another male character in it. I am finding that constantly using "policeman" is quite repetitive, clumsy and interrupts the flow. I have tried to improve this by using the policeman's rank at times (eg. captain) but I am looking for some alternatives.

I previously used "officer" but my understanding is that this can also be a rank or type of policeman? If so I am concerned about calling one person by two different ranks. Similarly "detective" and "inspector" came to mind but again, based on my research I believe these are more specifiers of a type of policeman not necessarily something that can be used as a synonym for one.

The only other idea I have come up with is to simply give the character a name, although I was trying to avoid that as I'm trying to distance the reader from this character.

Any suggestions at all?

Comment: What country? This is important.

Comment: "Officer of the law" is one term.  And there's "peace officer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A police officer can be referred to by several titles.

- Officer can be a generic term not denoting rank, position, or job function. Although it usually refers to a patrolman regardless of the patrolman’s rank (officer, corporal, sergeant, etc.)
- Patrolman can refer to a uniformed police officer, usually on patrol.
- Cop is an obvious choice.
- Copper is a little antiquated.
- LEO is short for Law Enforcement Officer. Many states and departments use this term to identify someone as a certificated and registered police officer.
- Five-O if you are street.

Comment: Note that LEO also applies to a number of non-police officers, including for example customs officers and immigration officers.

Answer (score 1):

**"Cop, "police officer," "law enforcement officer,"** or **"law enforcement agent"** could all work, but "cop" is likely the best choice.

> Cop: A police officer. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cop)]

> Police officer: A policeman or policewoman. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/police_officer)]

> Law enforcement officer: A government employee appointed to enforce the law, such as a police officer or sheriff. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/law_enforcement_officer)]

> Law enforcement agent: A police officer [[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/law-enforcement-agent)]

If you want to learn about the police ranks, visit [THIS](https://www.rasmussen.edu/degrees/justice-studies/blog/police-ranks/) site.  Then, you can decide what rank your policeman/woman is so you can use one more word to avoid naming them.

Answer (score 1):

[**Police officer**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/police%20officer) doesn't suggest any particular rank or type—any member of the police force can be referred to by that term:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : a member of a police force
> // there were *police officers* directing traffic around the scene of the accident

More informally, there is simply *officer* (again, no rank or type in this context) or *cop*, and slang terms, some with regional bias, include *copper*, *flatfoot*, and *bobby*.